# ¿Qué es recomendado hacer si necesito ponerle estilos distintos a cada hijo, usar una clase para cada hijo o usar nth-child?

Tags: css, buenas-prácticas

Supongamos que tengo el siguiente codigo:

```html
<div class="father">
  <div class="son1"></div>
  <div class="son2"></div>
  <div class="son3"></div>
  <div class="son4"></div>
  <!-- etc... -->
</div>
```

¿Qué es mejor práctica si necesito ponerle estilos distintos a cada hijo, usar una clase para cada hijo y poner `.clase: background-color: red` o poner `.son1:nth-child(x)`, y si ademas existe realmente una diferencia de rendimiento entre usar varias clases o nth-child()?

Comment: `nth-child()` es para estilos que dependen del orden, por ejemplo lineas pares fondo verde, o el cuarto siempre va en negrita, o en un responsive de tres columnas la del medio va con margenes. si los estilos para cada elemento son diferentes pero los mismos sin importar el orden, ahí usas una clase especifica y vicerveza

Answer (score 0):

Tambien puedes usar `div [class="son1"]{}`

[CSS Attribute Selector](https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_attribute_selectors.asp)